# cannot cast from view to MyListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am a novice in Android/JAVA.
I have a MyListViewPD like this and this can run as MainActivity :

```
public class MyListViewPD extends ListActivity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(),
            R.layout.vlist, new String[] { "title", "img" },
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.img });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
private List<Map<String, Object>> getData() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("title", "T1");
    map.put("img", R.drawable.i2);
    list.add(map);
      }
}
```

And I want this MyListViewPD can start as APP open,so I do this :

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyListViewPD listViewPD;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listViewPD = (MyListViewPD)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
}

}
```

but:

```
 listViewPD = (MyListViewPD)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

Cannot cast from View to MyListViewPD

I am not sure what happen but I guess it is a basic question..

Comment: try `setContentView(R.id.myListView)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyListViewPD is not a view. You defined it as an Activity.
Think you should read some more documentation :)

Comment: yes. i got the myListViewPD code from someone`s blog. :P but I cannot fully understood

Answer (score 0):

If you want your MyListViewPD can start as APP open,you'd better do this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourprojectname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/i2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyListViewPD"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note that any any Activity who has "intent-filter" as :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

can start as APP open.Hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list as view you should extend listview instead list activity and manage according to requirement. you can make customize row in xml for list view